# Tesseract OCR parameters

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to make OCR to images like this one
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyl8Z.jpg)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPn3R.jpg)

but it gives me a very bad result, which tesseract parameters would be better for these images

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('image.jpg'), lang='spa'))
```

Maybe changing the settings (psm oem) or maybe some preprocessing, I already tried some but not much better the result.

Comment: please write what did you tried (including code).